# Is there a way to emulate the __prepare__ special method of a Python 3-metaclass in Python 2.5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, metaclass

In my project I have to stick to Python 2.5 (Google App Engine). Somewhere in the application (actually a framework), I have to keep track which variables are defined and in which order they are defined, in other words I would like to intercept whenever an assignment operator is processed.

Using Python 3, I would define a metaclass M with a `__prepare__` method that returns an intelligent dictionary that keeps track of when it is accessed. Then I just have to execute everything inside a class statement with metaclass M.

Is there any way to emulate this in Python 2.5?

**EXAMPLE of what I would like to achieve**

With the metaclass approach of Python 3, I could implement variables that work like references, for example M could be so that

```
# y is a callable
class C(metaclass=M):
    x = ref(y)
    x = 1
```

would be equivalent (up to the creation of C) with `y(1)`, i.e. the first assignment to a variable in C's dictionary by a black-box `ref` function creates this variable. Further assignments simply call the parameter of the ref function.

Comment: I'm a little confused. Do you only want to execute the assignments in a class statement to keep track of order or do you actually want the resulting class?

Comment: @Aaron: I am only interested in how the dictionary is filled, not in the actual class resulting. Using the __new__ special method, I can even skip the creation of the resulting class, which already works in Python 2.5. I might use __new__, however, to report about my dictionary (in case it is created in __prepare__). Classes of metaclass M will then be dictionaries and not classes.

Comment: is ordereddict our of the ruled out? I really can't think of a way to do this although it is an interesting question.

Comment: @Aaron. I don't even know how to use an ordered dictionary with Python 2.5.

Comment: it would be easy enough to implement.

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap the variables you populate your classes with with a wrapper that internally keeps a counter and assigns an increasing value. The wrapper may be subclassed for tagging or to add behaviour to the variables. You would use the variable value to order them and a regular Python 2 metaclass to intercept the class creation.

Django is one of the projects that uses this technique to remember the order in which members are defined on a model class. You can take a look at [where the fields are created](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.3.x/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L59); it is then used in the implementation of the `__cmp__` method to keep the fields in the order of creation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing out the technique that is being used by Django. This would solve my problem with the relative order of the assignments. What it doesn't solve, however, is to keep track of the variables being assigned. I will edit my question to make this point clear in a moment.

Answer (score -1):

One place to start is by looking at [PEP-3115](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3115/) and reading about the "current" behavior, e.g. the behavior that was current before Python 3 was implemented.